# How do I post a Substrate dev job opportunity on https://careers.substrate.io/jobs?

Tags: advice

sorry for the dumb non-technical question.

I'd like to post [Bitgreen's Substrate Developer job opening](https://forms.gle/WzX3rvMzdBtAiqM19) on https://careers.substrate.io/jobs, but I don't see how to post it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would recommend posting this in Substrate Meta: https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

All teams that are part of the [Substrate Builders Program](https://substrate.io/ecosystem/substrate-builders-program/) can post their jobs into the job board. Currently [Getro](https://www.getro.com) is being used, which scrapes all the job posts for any given team across different platforms. Each company has it's own Admin to manage the information being displayed and the platforms to scrape. In particular, Adam is currently Bit Green's Admin, however this can be changed as well, either by adding more Admin's or changing them.

[All BitGreen's open positions](https://careers.substrate.io/jobs?q=bitGreen) are posted on the Job Board, these being sourced from `https://bitgreen.org/were-hiring`. To add any other source (the one pointed before seems not to be online), the Admin or Admins can edit that